# Calling JS Script AFTER wp_footer();

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm trying to add a script to the DOM right before `</body>`.  I know I can hook into `wp_footer()` with `add_action()` however, it seems no matter how I use `add_action()`, I'm still seeing two other JS snippets load after my script.

I have tried this code:

```
function myCustomScript() {
  if(!is_admin()) {
    wp_register_script( 'myCustomScript', 'external/path/to/js/file.js', false, '', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'myCustomScript' );
  }
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'myCustomScript');
```

[image: Current Code]

**My snippet is the teal/cyan color.**

I'm not sure if:

- My snippet won't go below the other two snippets because my snippet is set to defer and the other two aren't.
- My snippet won't go below the other two snippets because I'm not using the correct priority on `add_action()`, `wp_register_script()` or `wp_enqueue_script()`

I've read that executing JavaScript **after** `wp_footer()` could cause issues for other plugins perhaps but when I've called my JavaScript **after** `wp_footer()` -- I haven't seen any errors in the dev tools console.

#### Question:

- Is there any issue with adding my snippet **after** `wp_footer()`? If there is an issue with adding my snippet after `wp_footer()`, what is the recommended way to get my snippet (teal/cyan color) to the blank spot in the posted image.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

function myCustomScript() {

wp_enqueue_script( 'myCustomScript', get_template_directory_uri() . 'external/path/to/js/file.js', array(), '1.0', true );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myCustomScript' );

Answer (score 0):

Billy is correct, but some more information can be found here — https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/